# I am getting this error when i ran a flutter project from github... i tried everything

Tags: flutter

I am getting this error when i ran a flutter project from github... i tried everything.
i tried many command but no luck

```
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'headline'.
        theme.primaryTextTheme.headline;
                               ^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/velocity_x-0.3.4/lib/src/flutter/appbar.dart:338:45: Error: The getter 'body1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body1'.
    TextStyle sideStyle = widget.textTheme?.body1 ??
                                            ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/velocity_x-0.3.4/lib/src/flutter/appbar.dart:339:32: Error: The getter 'body1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body1'.
        appBarTheme.textTheme?.body1 ??
                               ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/velocity_x-0.3.4/lib/src/flutter/appbar.dart:340:32: Error: The getter 'body1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body1'.
        theme.primaryTextTheme.body1;
Launching lib\main.dart on Edge in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/velocity_x-0.3.4/lib/src/flutter/appbar.dart:322:57: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
    final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true);
                                                        ^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1769:24: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ScaffoldState of(BuildContext context) {
                       ^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/velocity_x-0.3.4/lib/src/flutter/appbar.dart:335:47: Error: The getter 'headline' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'headline'.

    TextStyle centerStyle = widget.textTheme?.headline ??
                                              ^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/velocity_x-0.3.4/lib/src/flutter/appbar.dart:336:32: Error: The getter 'headline' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'headline'.
        appBarTheme.textTheme?.headline ??
                               ^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/velocity_x-0.3.4/lib/src/flutter/appbar.dart:337:32: Error: The getter 'headline' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
                               ^^^^^
```

Failed to compile app.
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Please mention _what_ you tried.

Comment: i tried flutter clean ,create, pun upgrade  etc

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to use code written for an older version of flutter, that is the problem, you need to either downgrade your SDK or update the code.

Updating the code should be simple enough, most changes are very intuitive and IntelliSense can autocomplete what you don't know, however it seems like the original code used the getflutter package, which has since been discontinued and now is getWidget, I've never used neither, but the migration shouldn't be too hard.

If you are interested in updating the code here are the main changes I can see:

```
The getter 'body1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
```

just change `body1` to `bodyText1`

```
The getter 'headline' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
```

just change `headline` to `headline1`

And if what you want to do is downgrade the SDK, which might be the better option, simply download an older version from [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. but is still cant seem to fix it.    downgrade the SDK would be the last choice but I cant seem to fix this..

Comment: Dear, I have been having similar issues with almost any other repo as well, Please clone this and see for a while... what's the main issue: and why cant the flutter dart fix command cant fix it : https://github.com/iampawan/PortfolioX

Comment: Yep, found your problem, whoever added the dependencies added an outdated package, just change `velocity_x: ^0.3.4` to `velocity_x: ^3.3.0` on line 26 on the pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Thank you so so much.  how many people like me see this

Comment: glad it got resolved :)